# How to count occurrences of certain column value efficiently in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

I am using MySQL.

I have a table of `service_status`:

```
   id | service_id | service_status
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   0  | 1001       | download_started
   1  | 1001       | download_started
   2  | 1002       | download_started
   3  | 1002       | download_started
   4  | 1002       | download_failed
   5  | 1003       | download_started
   6  | 1003       | download_failed
   7  | 1003       | something_else
   8  | 1003       | another_thing
```

I want to query for all `service_id`s, and two additional columns that count the number of `download_started` and number of `download_failed`:

```
id | service id | download_started | download_failed
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0  | 1001       | 2                | 0
1  | 1002       | 2                | 1
2  | 1003       | 1                | 1
```

I only care about the statuses that are `download_started` or `download_failed`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  You should tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: is it mysql or sql server? if it is sql server you can use pivot

Comment: It's just mysql query.

Comment: count(col) group by col will give you the number of times each value occurs in a query.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff I'm new here.

Comment: do you have fixed set of service status?

Comment: How is `id` selected? Smallest `id` of a given `service id`? And is there a particular reason for non-existence of `service id` 1003 in the results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT 
    service_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN service_status = 'download_started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) download_started,
    SUM(CASE WHEN service_status = 'download_failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) download_failed
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY 
    service_id
ORDER BY 
    service_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can simplify the expression to:

```
SELECT service_id,
       SUM(service_status = 'download_started') as download_started,
       SUM(service_status = 'download_failed') as download_failed
FROM t
GROUP BY service_id;
```